# Handling IP Changes for Master MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, replication

I have been working with master-slave replication in MySQl and was wondering if there is any possibility to set the listen-address property of the MYSQL config file to read the IP statically assigned to host (and may be grabbed using nbtstat -n | find "IpAddress:" and saved as a system variable). The reason is that I do not want any IP changes to affect replication. In that case, I will entirely rely on the reboot that the involved team does after the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the replication user with the host IP on the Master

```
CREATE USER 'static_repl'@'10.20.30.253' ... ;
GRANT REPLICATION USER,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* to 'static_repl'@'10.20.30.253';
```

If you have an IP range in mind, use that range

```
CREATE USER 'static_repl'@'10.20.%' ... ;
GRANT REPLICATION USER,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* to 'static_repl'@'10.20.%';
```

Then, stop the slave, delete the user that is not static from the master, and start the slave.

Comment: I was worried of the listen-address on masters config file. Anyway to handle this dynamically? apart from the 0.0.0.0 setting.